# How to build executable ARM64-V8 program with OpenCL and fastcv for running on Android?

Tags: android, opencl, arm64, fastcv

I want to build a C++ program in **arm64-v8a** running on Android, which used OpenCL and fastCV. I can compile and work well when I use the **armv7-a** architecture.
Please help me if you know how to figure it out

Application.mk:

```
APP_CPPFLAGS = -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI:= armeabi-v7a-hard
APP_STL:=gnustl_static
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libOpenCL32
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./prelibs/libs32/libOpenCL.so 
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libfastcvopt32
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./prelibs/libs32/libfastcvopt.so 
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
MY_SRC_LIST += $(wildcard ./*.cpp)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ./
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(MY_SRC_LIST)

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cxx .cpp .cc    
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DSUPPORT_OMP -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -fopenmp -fexceptions -fpermissive -Wno-literal-suffix -Wl,--no-as-needed -std=c++11 -O3 -Wl,  -hash-style=sysv
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L./libs32
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lm -lz -lc -llog -pie -fPIE  -fopenmp 
LOCAL_MODULE := testQcom
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libOpenCL32 libfastcvopt32 
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

When I compile the source code using the .mk like these, everything is ok, and program works well. But when I want to compile the program in **arm64-v8a**, errors occur.

The arm64-v8a Application.mk:

```
APP_CPPFLAGS = -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI:= arm64-v8a 
APP_STL:=gnustl_static
```

The arm64-v8a Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libOpenCL64
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./prelibs/libs64/libOpenCL.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libfastcvopt64
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./prelibs/libs64/libfastcvopt.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
MY_SRC_LIST += $(wildcard ./*.cpp)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ./
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(MY_SRC_LIST)

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cxx .cpp .cc    
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DSUPPORT_OMP -march=armv8-a -fopenmp -fexceptions -fpermissive -Wno-literal-suffix -Wl,--no-as-needed -std=c++11 -O3 -Wl,  -hash-style=sysv
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L./libs64
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lm -lz -lc -llog -pie -fPIE  -fopenmp 
LOCAL_MODULE := testQcom
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libOpenCL64 libfastcvopt64 
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

The error is:

> [arm64-v8a] Executable     : testQcom
>   /home/liliming/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: libgsl.so, needed by .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /home/liliming/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: libCB.so, needed by .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /home/liliming/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: libcutils.so, needed by .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /home/liliming/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: libc++.so, needed by .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_end_perf_monitor_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_write_buffer'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_release_device'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`sleep@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_wait_for_events'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_migrate_mem_objects'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `exp@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_set_command_queue_property'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_platform_ids'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`open@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_native_kernel'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`pthread_mutex_init@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_unmap_mem_object'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`memcmp@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_pipe_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_read_buffer'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_release_gl_objects'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`__cxa_atexit@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_release_perf_monitor_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_fill_buffer'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_program_with_binary'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`os_strncmp'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_platform_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_get_gl_texture_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_retain_device'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`g_alogDebugMask'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `sin@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`dlopen@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_write_buffer_rect'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_sub_devices'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_release_mem_object'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_svm_mem_fill'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_acquire_egl_objects_khr'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_release_context'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_set_mem_object_destructor_callback'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_barrier'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`sysconf@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `atan@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_copy_buffer'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `strlen@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`dlerror@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_image3d'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_perf_monitor_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_unload_compiler'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_retain_context'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_retain_program'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_read_buffer_rect'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `puts@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`strlcpy@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_kernel_arg_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`__register_atfork@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_sub_buffer'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_get_kernel_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `get_panel_settings'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`cos@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `os_alog'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_build_program'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_pipe'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_marker'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_marker_with_wait_list'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_get_sync_obj_from_cl_event_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_svm_free'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`strtoul@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_retain_sampler'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_x_nd_range_kernel_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_copy_image_to_buffer'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_get_supported_image_formats'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `fclose@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_get_program_build_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `atoi@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`strtol@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `dlsym@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`__errno@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_destroy@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_buffer'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `fread@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_buffer_from_image_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_gl_context_info_khr'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`acosf@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `tan@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_retain_perf_monitor_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_program_with_builtinkernels'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`pthread_once@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_write_image'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`close@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_nd_range_kernel'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`snprintf@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_command_queue_with_properties'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`dlclose@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_from_gl_texture3d'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_from_egl_image_img'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_read_perf_monitor_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_copy_buffer_to_image'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_task'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`pthread_detach@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `ftell@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`atan2@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `strlcat@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_release_kernel'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_retain_mem_object'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`pclose@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_mem_object_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_get_event_profiling_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_set_event_callback'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`gettimeofday@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `strnlen@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_map_buffer'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_event_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_from_gl_renderbuffer'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_from_gl_texture2d'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_get_command_queue_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_svm_alloc'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`__signbitf@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_read_image'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`printf@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_image'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_kernel_work_group_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_kernels_in_program'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_perf_monitor_info_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_get_gl_object_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `fopen@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`strcmp@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_common_unlock_global_mutex'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_compile_program'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`pthread_create@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_svm_memcpy'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`cosf@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `memset@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_retain_command_queue'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`free@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_finish'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_event_wait_for_submission_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `memchr@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_copy_buffer_rect'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `vsnprintf@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_set_perf_hint_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_device_ids'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_set_kernel_arg'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `fseek@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_copy_image'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_sampler_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_get_image_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_release_egl_objects_khr'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`log@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_map_image'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_svm_unmap'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `sinf@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`__cxa_finalize@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_release_sampler'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_kernel'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_program_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`malloc@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_svm_map'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_flush'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_device_image_info_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_get_device_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `lrint@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`popen@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_retain_event'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_from_gl_buffer'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`strncmp@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_event_from_egl_sync_khr'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`pow@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_platform_compiler_unload'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`mmap@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_context_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_release_program'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `strrchr@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`memalign@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `fgets@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_from_gl_texture'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_image2d'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_program_with_source'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_sampler'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_begin_perf_monitor_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_command_queue'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_svm_free'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_release_command_queue'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_get_perf_monitor_group_info_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `property_get'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_set_kernel_exec_info'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_create_from_egl_image_khr'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`ioctl@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `exit@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_context_from_type'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `munmap@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_acquire_gl_objects'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_get_kernel_sub_group_info_khr'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_enqueue_barrier_with_wait_list'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_set_kernel_arg_svm_pointer'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_get_perf_monitor_counter_info_qcom'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_enqueue_fill_image'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_sampler_with_properties'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_retain_kernel'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to`memmem@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `read@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_wait_for_events'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `pthread_join@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_context'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_link_program'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_set_user_event_status'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `cb_common_lock_global_mutex'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_create_user_event'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfastcvopt.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock@LIBC'
>   .//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to`cb_release_event'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/testQcom] Error 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I modified one statement in the Android.mk like this:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -fuse-ld=gold
```

Everything does work！

Comment: I couldn't link my binary with OpenCL until you gave this solution. Thank you.